# ubuntu 14.04 touchpad settings disappeared on dell latitude e5530

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad

after the release upgrade to 14.04, the touchpad settings disappeared on my dell latitude e5530. Has anyone the same problem? Do you know how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem on multiple occasions except on my System76 Serval 
Professional laptop.

It appears to be a bug a temporary solution to fix it is normally to restart Ubuntu.
I don't know of any other fixes but to report the bug if possible or wait until a bugfix.